# Mathematica + Pythonika on the Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, python

Due to the high availability of python code for the rpi, I'm trying to call python functions from Mathematica. I know that pythonika works well on OS X, but I can't compile it on the Raspberry pi.

This is the repository for pythonika:

https://github.com/erocarrera/pythonika

I suspect that I need to change the Makefile.linux to match Raspberry pi settings. But so far I havent been able to succeed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to do it. I'll post what I did in case somebody else needs it. So far it works really nice. Just follow the instructions from the repository, and modify the `Makefile.linux` with the following code, saved as `Makefile.linux`:

```bash
# Set the paths according to your MathLink Developer Kit location.
# (The paths should not contain whitespaces)

MATHEMATICA_INSTALL_DIR = /opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/10.3
MLINKDIR = ${MATHEMATICA_INSTALL_DIR}/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit

SYS = Linux-ARM
CADDSDIR = ${MLINKDIR}/${SYS}/CompilerAdditions

INCDIR = ${CADDSDIR}
LIBDIR = ${CADDSDIR}

MPREP = "${CADDSDIR}/mprep"
MCC = "${CADDSDIR}/mcc"

# Modify the following for Python versions other than 2.6
PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR = 2
PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR = 7


# Path to the Python includes (modify according to Python version)
#
PYTHONINC = /usr/include/python${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR}/


PYTHONIKA = Pythonika
INCLUDES = -I${INCDIR} -I${PYTHONINC}

# libstdc++ and librt are, apparently, needed for correct compilation under Linux
# with libMLi3 statically linked
#
LIBS = -L${LIBDIR} ${LIBDIR}/libML32i4.a -lstdc++ -lrt -lm -pthread -luuid -ldl -lpython${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR}


all : Pythonika

Pythonika: ${PYTHONIKA}.o ${PYTHONIKA}tm.o
    ${CC} ${INCLUDES} ${PYTHONIKA}.o ${PYTHONIKA}tm.o ${LIBS} -o ${PYTHONIKA}

${PYTHONIKA}tm.o: ${PYTHONIKA}.tm
    ${MPREP} ${PYTHONIKA}.tm -o ${PYTHONIKA}tm.c
 ${CC} -c ${PYTHONIKA}tm.c ${INCLUDES}

${PYTHONIKA}.o: ${PYTHONIKA}.c
    ${CC} -c ${PYTHONIKA}.c ${INCLUDES}

clean :
    rm -f ${PYTHONIKA}tm.* ${PYTHONIKA}.o ${PYTHONIKA}
```

Now open the Pythonika.nb notebook and run the code.

I'll update this if I find any issues.

Comment: I edited your post directly include the code rather than your google drive file, which is less permanent.